# Count data slow use relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$user = User::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->withCount([
        'posts as success' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
         },
         'posts as error' => function ($query) {
             $query->whereIn('status', [1, 2, 3]);
         },
     ])                
     ->where('order', 3)
     ->get();
```

Model `Post.php`:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Model `User.php` :

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

I want to count `status` in the `post` table through relationship. Like the above code, I got the result I wanted. But it is very slow, about 10 seconds or more. Is there any way to fix it? My post table has `400,000 data`

I have index the status column in the post table.

Comment: Add index in tables https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#indexes

Comment: @Davit I have index the status column in the post table.